# Azure AD B2C Sign in

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We want to build a .NET and Angular application which our internal users and invited external users can have access. We initially tried to build that by connecting to our internal azure-ad but that would mean that external users are part of our internal azure ad. One approach was to use Azure B2C AD but then not sure of how to get internal users in that AD without duplication. Eventually, we will have roles for users and wanted to check if we can avoid duplication of maintenance in multiple azure AD.

Hopefully, we are not doing something new i.e. creating an application that can be used by internal employees with their office 365 credentials and allowing invited external users to access the same application. Roles govern what part of the functionality is accessible within the application.

What are the possible approaches / recommended approach?

Answer (score 1):

Use AAD B2C and add AAD as an identity provider to B2C, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow).